# Transferring the events to parent view (Titanium Studio, IPhone)

Tags: iphone, ios, events, titanium-mobile, transfer

I am new to mobile development with Titanium Studio. I would like to know if it is possible to transfer an event to a view's parent view.

For example, say that I have a imageview namely imgVw added on top of a view namely parentView and I want to pass the touch event of imgVw to parentView. Please let me know if it is possible. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please try this:

A simple technique is to set the **touchEnabled** property of child view to **false**, which passes the event to the parent view. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a custom eventListener. and you can fire that event when user touches the image view. and you can even pass the argument to the event.

in your parent View define a custom eventListener

```
Ti.App.addEventListener('imageTouch',function(e) {
  //This `e` will hold the  argument passed
});
```

now when you touch the Image view

add an eventListener to your ImageView to capture the touch event,

```
myImage.addEventListener('touch',function(e) {
     //Now fire your custom event here, this will take you to the custom 
     // event defined in your parent view
     Ti.App.fireEvent('imageTouch',{
        touchArg:[e] // here we save your touch callback in an array `touchArg` and pass this to the custom eventListener.
     });
 });
```

hope that helped :)